# Best way to rotate content within a DIV using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, see the [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) website. It's only going to be used to rotate through about 3-5 "ads" to noteworthy areas of the site. I'd like to have some kind of link control to backtrack to the other content (again, like the MySQL site). Google gives me a bunch of very easy to implement stuff for the rotation itself, it's the link control that is difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the [cycle plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for jQuery to be very versatile. It can rotate elements in several ways and can add a next / prev control menu.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. It even supports a "pager," which is what the MySQL page has. Thanks again.